# how can i make custom icons on a polyline?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am in the midst of converting old googlemap v2 code to v3. Now i stumble upon a problem how to create custom markers for a polyline? I managed to create custom markers just for points on a map. But when i use the "new" google.maps.Polyline to create a route/path i don't now how i can set custom markers.

I don't have a reference to the individul markers

```
 var flightPlanCoordinates = [
new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897),
new google.maps.LatLng(21.291982, -157.821856),
new google.maps.LatLng(-18.142599, 178.431),
new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46758, 153.027892)
];
var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
path: flightPlanCoordinates,
strokeColor: "#FF0000",
strokeOpacity: 1.0,
strokeWeight: 2
});
```

i tried flightPlanCoordinates.setIcon("img/icon.jpg");

In my case i like to use 3 different icons (start, doing, finished).

back in v2 i had a switch function

```
function returnGIcon(type) {
var icon =  new GIcon(); 
switch(type) {
```

And i used

```
for(i=1;i<points.length-1;i++) {
marker = new GMarker(points[i],{icon:returnGIcon('doing')});
map.addOverlay(marker);
}
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

A polyline shows a line between the points and does not add markers. If you still want to show a marker on each (specified) point on the polyline you need to add a GMarker on those points. So basically you create both the line and the GMarkers like you did before.

Comment: wow and i thought i missed an important v3 function. Is GMarker still part of V3, hence do you know a cheatsheet which compares the main difference between v2 and v3?

Comment: http://markus.tao.at/geo/google-maps-api-v3-is-in-town/ or www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-AskKI_10Y (not really a cheatsheet though)

Comment: hmm, combining both api doesn't work nicely. In v2 i had points, like points.push(new GLatLng(%s, %s) and in v3 i have new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897). As i am using the points array to attach the icons how do i use the new coordinates array??

Comment: Not sure what your problem is. The new LatLng objects you have in your flightPlan array are the same type as what you need to create a marker (marker = new Marker({position: flightPlan[0]}); For the different image types you can use ImageMarkers. See: http://code.google.com/intl/nl-NL/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MarkerOptions